# JSONArray to ArrayList<MyObject>

Tags: java, json, json-simple

Is it possible using **json-simple** (and no other additional library) to convert a `JSONArray` to an `ArrayList<MyObject>`?

I was not able to find code samples in the documentation nor on SO.

This is how I do it at the moment (quite a bit complicated):

```
for(Iterator iterator = jsonRootObject.keySet().iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    String key = (String) iterator.next();
    JSONObject jsonEpg = (JSONObject) jsonRootObject.get(key);
    JSONArray jsonEpgTags = (JSONArray) jsonEpg.get("tags");

    //Iterate tags
    for(int i = 0; i < jsonEpgTags.size(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonEpgTag = (JSONObject) jsonEpgTags.get(i);
        final String tagId = (String) jsonEpgTag.get("id");
        String name = (String) jsonEpgTag.get("name");

        EpgJsonTagValue jsonTagValue = new EpgJsonTagValue();
        jsonTagValue.tagId = tagId;
        jsonTagValue.name = name;

        result.add(jsonTagValue);
    }
}
```

My "POJO":

```
public class EpgJsonTagValue {
    private String tagId;
    private String name;

    public String getTagId() {
        return tagId;
    }

    public void setTagId(String id) {
        this.tagId = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "TagId: " + tagId
                + ", Name: " + name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You `join` the elements using a `separator` `String`, then `split` them to get an array, then pass this array to `Arrays.asList` which will be passed to the constructor of `ArrayList`.

```
public static ArrayList<Object> JSONArray2ArrayList(JSONArray input, Class c) {
    return new ArrayList<c>(Arrays.asList(input.join(separator).split(separator)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to iterate JsonArray object to build a list. Its already implements List interface so just type cast it, like below

```
List<UserObject> result = (List<UserObject>) jsonArray;
```

Please try and let me know.

Comment: No, it is inherited from java.lang.Object and does not implement the list interface. Please, next time when you answer a question make sure that your answer is correct.

Comment: http://juliusdavies.ca/json-simple-1.1.1-javadocs/org/json/simple/JSONArray.html

Doc says its JsonArray implements List

Comment: Then it is worth a try :)

Comment: Well, it doesn't throw an error but the List is still a list with `JSONObject`s. So didn't solve my problem.

Comment: I Understand, now converting JSONObject to user object is Challenging..!

Answer (score 0):

This will work for sure!!

```
List<EpgJsonTagValue> epgJsonTagValueList = (List<EpgJsonTagValue>)jsonEpgTags ;
```

Or if you want an ArrayList then this will work:

```
ArrayList<EpgJsonTagValue> epgJsonTagValueList = (ArrayList<EpgJsonTagValue>)jsonEpgTags ;
```